# My media querys aren't working in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm still learning BootStrap and have managed to design my page but now I'm figuring out the screen sizing, specifically the carousel. I'm trying to make the carousel change height when I make the screen smaller, but for some reason nothing changes when I write my media querys.

[This is what I'm trying to achieve, the first two screens are mine, the other two are the website I'm trying to replicate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVwA8.jpg)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="opacify9 bgwidth" src="img/Carousel_CW_Test.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Civil War</h1>
            <p>Protect The Future</p>
            <p>Change the Future</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Order Now</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active left">
      <img class="opacify7 bgwidth" src="img/Test_Carousel_Saga_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Saga</h1>
            <p>Buy The Latest Issue Of The Epic Space Opera</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Check It Out!</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item next left">
      <img class="bgheight" src="img/Test_Carousel_SW_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Secret Wars</h1>
          <p>The Final Issue Drawing Jonathan Hickmans Epic Story To A Conclusion</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Join Us</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

This is the media query CSS that I have written

```
/* Portrait & Landscape Phone */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

.carousel, .carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 325px;
}
}


/* Landscape Phone To Portrait Tabelt */
@media (max-width: 991px) {


 }
 /* Large Desktop */

 @media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

Comment: where you put this custom css ? can you share file ? or give just link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IzcIPSxf-tMy01cUp1Q0h2enM/view?usp=sharing

thats the project folder I'm working on - If anyones able to take a quick look

Comment: you need to learn some basic html and css you did alot of mistakes you need to learn bootstrap firs how to custom bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your could be that bootstrap properties for carousel will be overwriting your custom CSS properties. In order to solve it you can mention !important in front of your custom css like

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

.carousel, .carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 325px !important;
}
}
```

However a better way will be to add your `custom css` file in the document after you load the `bootstrap`.

Comment: I tried the !important tag but nothing changed either, still not sure what you mean when you say, add your custom css file in the document after you load the bootstrap. 

my bootstrap is linked in the html but I don't have another css file

Comment: your carousel is working in the jsfiddle I tried. https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/mmh283pc/

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because of previous CSS syntax errors, if you try to validate it as is, you will get the following errors:

> **Line 36:**  [h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6]    Property family-font doesn't exist : inherit

This should be: `font-family: inherit;`

> **Line 167:** [.carousel-indicators li]   Property border-raidus doesn't exist : 10px

This should be: `border-radius: 10px`

> **Line 221:** [.carousel-caption btn] Parse Error (0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,002)

This should be:

```
.carousel-caption .btn {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

> **Line 233:** [.carousel-control] Property text-sahdow doesn't exist : 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)

This should be: `text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);`

---

The real issue here was the `box-shadow` property at line 221. The other errors wouldn't affect your CSS file but this one made all rules after it ignored.

So please be careful when you write code and try validating before asking on SO.

CSS Validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/